# Convert number into HH24:Mi:SS where Mi:SS is a concatenated string

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to convert a number field to HH24 (brc_frm_tme) and concatenate the minutes and seconds as ':00:00'. The number field could be 7 or 13 but I want the leading zero. My select statement is as follows:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(to_char(schd_entry_dte) || to_char(brc_frm_tme, '00') || ':00:00', 'DD-MON-RR FXHH24:Mi:SS') from wcm729;
```

which returns the following result: 02-SEP-99 13:**0:0** and 02-SEP-99 7:**0:0**.
How can I get the minutes and seconds to display correctly?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Took the FX out and I get the same results. Thanks.

Comment: Your client is formatting the timestamp like that. If you're running this in SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer or similar, what is `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` set to in your session? Your client may have a preference that overrides that but it's the first thing I'd check. (Also what data type is `schd_entry_dte`; and why are you storing date and time separately?)

Comment: @Alex - thank you; I looked at the NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT in my session and it was FMHH24:Mi:SS. When I removed the FM, I got the desired results.

Comment: try this SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100)

Comment: @Raghavendra - this question is for Oracle, so that syntax isn't valid.

Comment: I get the correct results when I use a SELECT but does not work when using an INSERT - why would there be a difference? I get the ORA-01843: not a valid month error

Answer (score 2):

Your client is formatting the timestamp you are generating, either via the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session setting or via a preference set in the client. If you change that to not suppress leading zeros it will display as you want.

You seem to be doing too much work though. As `schd_entry_dte` appears to be a date you can add time directly to it:

```
select schd_entry_dte + brc_frm_tme/24 from wcm729;
```

or

```
select schd_entry_dte + brc_frm_tme * interval '1' hour from wcm729;
```

both of which give you a date value; or if you want a timestamp cast the date or the result:

```
select cast(schd_entry_dte as timestamp) + brc_frm_tme * interval '1' hour from wcm729;
select cast(schd_entry_dte + brc_frm_tme * interval '1' hour  as timestamp) from wcm729;
```

Demo:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1';

select schd_entry_dte, brc_frm_tme,
  schd_entry_dte + brc_frm_tme/24 as date_a,
  schd_entry_dte + brc_frm_tme * interval '1' hour as date_b
from wcm729;

SCHD_ENTRY_DTE       BRC_FRM_TME DATE_A               DATE_B              
-------------------- ----------- -------------------- --------------------
 1999-09-02 00:00:00           7  1999-09-02 07:00:00  1999-09-02 07:00:00
 1999-09-02 00:00:00          13  1999-09-02 13:00:00  1999-09-02 13:00:00

select schd_entry_dte, brc_frm_tme,
  cast(schd_entry_dte as timestamp) + brc_frm_tme * interval '1' hour as timestamp_a,
  cast(schd_entry_dte + brc_frm_tme * interval '1' hour  as timestamp) as timestamp_b
from wcm729;

SCHD_ENTRY_DTE       BRC_FRM_TME TIMESTAMP_A            TIMESTAMP_B           
-------------------- ----------- ---------------------- ----------------------
 1999-09-02 00:00:00           7  1999-09-02 07:00:00.0  1999-09-02 07:00:00.0
 1999-09-02 00:00:00          13  1999-09-02 13:00:00.0  1999-09-02 13:00:00.0
```

An Oracle date includes a time portion, even if you don't see it because of your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` settings. If you have a non-midnight time that you want to treat as midnight you can `trunc()` the date. With slightly different source data:

```
select schd_entry_dte, brc_frm_tme,
  cast(trunc(schd_entry_dte) as timestamp) + brc_frm_tme * interval '1' hour as timestamp_a,
  cast(trunc(schd_entry_dte) + brc_frm_tme * interval '1' hour  as timestamp) as timestamp_b
from wcm729;

SCHD_ENTRY_DTE       BRC_FRM_TME TIMESTAMP_A            TIMESTAMP_B           
-------------------- ----------- ---------------------- ----------------------
 1999-09-02 01:23:45           7  1999-09-02 07:00:00.0  1999-09-02 07:00:00.0
 1999-09-02 12:13:14          13  1999-09-02 13:00:00.0  1999-09-02 13:00:00.0
```